# python .readlines() utf-8/latin-1 encoding crazy mistake

Tags: python, character-encoding

Im writing a program which stick together some hh-suite programs... but i have a problem with something realy strange - when script must .readlines() it stops on one file in turn with error `unicodedecodeerror: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position : invalid continuation byte' codec can't decode byte` so i change it to 'latin-1' and result is the same...

I use 'ignore' and error is omitted

```
 open('./PFAM/' + seq_file_PFAM_hhr,'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore')
```

but its very annoying, I do not know whats wrong.

Comment: what is "hh-suite"? Where does the file come from, and what are you expecting it to contain? Do you know what the encoding is *supposed to* be? Are you sure the contents of the file are even supposed to represent text?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel its bioinformatic suite of programs(https://github.com/soedinglab/hh-suite/wiki) I do not know, but I think it is suppouse to be UTF-8 or latin-1 encodeing (programs was made at Max Plank Insitiutein Germany) Files came from program as just txt files.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel here: https://toolkit.tuebingen.mpg.de/jobs/peak3 are similar output from their server (in the tab raw output) Maybe i ask wrong can i recognize encoding and if its wrong  change it?

Comment: Hmm, quite strange. The sample output looks like plain ASCII that should be fine either way, and 'latin-1' is supposed to be able to decode any byte (though the result might not be what you want). Can you produce a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)? For example, pick a file that causes the problem, and remove content from it to isolate what is causing the problem. Also, could you show the context of this code (at least between the `open` call and the `readlines` call, and enough for someone else to run)?

Comment: Often it is useful to create a program which read a character and write a character in a new file, one character per loop. So you can see exactly where there is the error. Or use `"backslashreplace"` and look in the file. You should have hint where the error come. Often on a file there are dataset in an extra encoding.